# invalidoperationexception was unhandled by user code in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

An exception of type 'system.invalidoperation exception occurred in BHEBS.dll but was not handled by usercode.
additional information: BHEBS.fService: The LastChgUserId Field is required.

public int PostService(ModalfService objSR)
        {
            int i = -1;

```
            using (EBStestConnection db = new EBStestConnection())
            {
                fService entitysr = new fService();
                entitysr = objSR.ToEntity();
                db.fServices.Add(entitysr);



                //db.SaveChanges();
                //i = entitysr.Id;

                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                {
                    Exception raise = dbEx;

                    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {

                        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                        {

                            string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                                validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                                validationError.ErrorMessage);
                            // raise a new exception nesting
                            // the current instance as InnerException
                            raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                        }
                    }
                    throw raise;
                }
            }


        return i;
    }
```

Comment: The exception is very Clear

Comment: Your fservice requires LastChgUserId. How are you setting it?

Comment: I have 4 fields in the db . the servicename, desc, lastchg userid and lstchgdate.  I did not set any thing for LastChgUserId.  actually in my db LastChgUserId can be Null. I am entering only  servicename, desc,  fields from Ui